# Negative lookahead but with something before it

Tags: regex

I'm using a regex to parse some HTML I have the following regex which matches all tags except img and a.

```
 \<(?!img|a)[^\>]+\>
```

This works well but I also want it to match the closing tags, I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
 \</?(?!img|a)[^\>]+\>
```

What would be the best way to do this?

(Also before there is a plethora of comments saying not to use regexes to parse HTML I'd just like to say that this HTML is generated by a tool and is very uniform.)

EDIT:

```
 <p>So in this</p>
 <p>HTML <strong>with nested tags</strong></p>
 <p>It should remove <i>everything</i> except <a href="#">This link</a>
 and this <img src="#" alt="image" /> but it also needs to kep the textual content</p>
```

Comment: someone saying to not parse html with regex below...

Comment: \</?(?!img|a)[^\>].*?(?=\>) this would work. it ends with the first match of \?

Comment: you dont need to scape < or > since they are not special characters, you missed "/" and didnt scape this one... it should be \/?

Comment: @JoeNFU can you give an example of what link you dont want to match?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Your right about the escaping - I've added an example of the html

Comment: jtbandes - not a duplicate of that question since I'm saying to exclude certain tags. I do like the accepted answer though.

Comment: <(?!(img|a)).+>.*?(?=>) try this please

Comment: Hi Val it doesn't work (in expresso at least) just tweaking it now cos it seems almost there. EDIT: On second thoughts it won't match closing tags. The one above didn't work either. (It matched '</a' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the simplest solution would be the following:

```
<\/?(?!img|a)[^>]+>
```

It simply matches:

- a `<`,
- a `/` (escaped with `\`) if there is any (quantifier `?`),
- asserts that there is neither `img` nor `a`,
- a sequence of anything but `>` (`[^>]+`) and
- a `>`

See it working [here on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/rI5nH5/1).

Comment: Hmm ok that works, I've put it in to my javascript and it works too. It just doesn't work in Expresso - must be a bug. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a pretty wasteful solution:

```
   <(?!img|a|\/img|\/a)[^>]+>
```

It would be great if someone could find a better one.